# Differences between unions vs union of differences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A_n, B_n \subset \mathbb{R}$ for $n \geq 1$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is it true that:

\begin{equation*}
\bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n  - \bigcup_{n \geq 1} B_n = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n - B_n
\end{equation*}

I couldn't find a counter example but couldn't manage to prove either. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the $A_n,B_n$ supposed to be nested? If not take $A_2=\{1\}=B_1,$ and all other $A_n,B_n=\emptyset.$ You should be able to show how they are different in that case, no?

Comment: It is trivially true for $n=1$, but not true in general. Say $A_1=\{1\},A_2=\{2\},B_1=\{3\},B_2=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect. Consider $A_n=\{1,n\}$ and $B_n=\{n\}$ for all $n.$ Then $$\bigcup_{n\ge 1} A_n=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}B_n=\Bbb N,$$ but $$\Bbb N-\Bbb N=\emptyset\ne\{1\}=\bigcup_{n\ge1}A_n-B_n.$$

Rather, we should use DeMorgan's laws. Given any $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ and any sets $B_n\subseteq\Bbb R$ for $n\in\Bbb N,$ we have

\begin{eqnarray}A-\bigcup_{n\ge 1}B_n &=& A\cap\left(\Bbb R-\bigcup_{n\ge 1}B_n\right)\\ &=& A\cap\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\Bbb R-B_n\\ &=& \bigcap_{n\ge 1}A\cap(\Bbb R-B_n)\\ &=& \bigcap_{n\ge 1}A-B_n.\end{eqnarray}

Since intersections distribute over unions, then

\begin{eqnarray}\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n-\bigcup_{n\ge 1}B_n &=& \left(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n\right)\cap\left(\Bbb R-\bigcup_{n\ge 1}B_n\right)\\ &=& \left(\bigcup_{m\ge 1}A_m\right)\cap\left(\Bbb R-\bigcup_{n\ge 1}B_n\right)\\ &=& \bigcup_{m\ge 1}A_m\cap\left(\Bbb R-\bigcap_{n\ge 1}B_n\right)\\ &=& \bigcup_{m\ge 1}\left(A_m-\bigcup_{n\ge 1}B_n\right)\\ &=& \bigcup_{m\ge 1}\bigcap_{n\ge 1}A_m-B_n.\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 4):

$A_1 = A_2 = [0,1]$ and $B_1 = \mathbb{R}, B_2 = \emptyset$.

Then $\cup_n A_n \setminus \cup_n B_n = \emptyset$ but
$\cup_n (A_n \setminus B_n) = [0,1]$.